# How to include font into css file

Tags: css, angular, angular8

I have a css file which I included into Angular project this way:

```
{
  "styles" : [
        "src/assets/css/style.css"
  ],
}
```

Into angular.json I added:

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

But into the css file font files are loaded like:

```
src: url("assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=1.4.57");
src: url("assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=1.4.57") format("embedded-opentype"), url("assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=1.4.57") format("woff2"),
```

I get error:

```
Can't resolve 'assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf'
```

And many more other like this.
What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: you have this file in your assets folder?

Comment: Yes, I do but it's not found

Comment: have you checked in dist/assets/fonts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your font as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"Your font";
  src: url("assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=1.4.57"),
       url("assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=1.4.57") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=1.4.57") format("woff2");
}
```

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

I usually include my fonts like this :

```
@font-face {    font-family: "Nunito Light"; font-display: swap;    src: url('../font/Nunito/Nunito-Light.ttf'); }
```

You should just include .ttf file of your fonts instead of including .eot, .woff2

here : [Everythings fonts](https://everythingfonts.com/woff2-to-ttf)

you can change .woff2 font to .ttf font

Comment: But what if I have also `src: url(assets/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot?v=1.4.57);` ? with some data?

Comment: for me just the .ttf file should be enougth and I do not understand why at the end, you've wrote ?v=1.4.57

Comment: This is from the original template.